# How do I fix the syntax error 'do'?

Tags: bash, scripts

Here is a program I am working with but this is the output.

```
echo "Please select your favorite color"
echo "         or 4 to exit"
echo "---------------------------------"

#set menu prompt
menu="select color : "

#set menu list
select menu in Blue Yellow Red Quit
do
       case $menu in
               Blue)
                        echo "----------------------------"
                        echo "Your favorite color is Blue!"
                        echo "----------------------------"
                        ;;
               Yellow)
                        echo "----------------------------"
                        echo "Your favorite color is Yellow!"
                        echo "----------------------------"
                        ;;
               Red)
                        echo "----------------------------"
                        echo "Your favorite color is Red!"
                        echo "----------------------------"
                        ;;
               Quit)
                        echo "----------------------------"
                        echo "Thank you!"
                        echo "----------------------------"
                        ;;           
               *)
                        echo -e "Error: please try again (select 1......4)!"
       esac
```

```
Please select your favorite color
         or 4 to exit
./select.sh: line 36: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

how do I fix it?
Background: I'm brand new to linux and coding so I barely have any understanding to what's going on. I'm 100% youtube university

---

**Edit:** #?4 Error: please try again (select 1....4)! –

```
echo "Please select your favorite color"
echo "         or 4 to exit"
echo "---------------------------------"

#set menu prompt
menu="select color : "

#set menu list
select menu in Blue Yellow Red Quit
do
       case $menu in
               Blue)
                        echo "----------------------------"
                        echo "Your favorite color is Blue!"
                        echo "----------------------------"
                        ;;
               Yellow)
                        echo "----------------------------"
                        echo "Your favorite color is Yellow!"
                        echo "----------------------------"
                        ;;
               Red)
                        echo "----------------------------"
                        echo "Your favorite color is Red!"
                        echo "----------------------------"
                        ;;
               Quit)
                        echo "----------------------------"
                        echo "Thank you!"
                        echo "----------------------------"
                        ;;           
               *)
                        echo -e "Error: please try again (select 1......4)!"
       esac
done
```

Comment: The error message `./select.sh: line 9: Select: command not found` is explicit. `Select` is not found. You want to use `select` instead.

Comment: ALWAYS always paste the code! Because this is a community based! Your code should be visible as both eyes to you and the community, your question/answers should be relevant to all! Not just you.

Comment: Sorry about that now I'm getting

Comment: ./select.sh: line 37: syntax error: unexpected end of file, why does this happen?

Comment: From your image you posted, you didn't close out your `do` loop with `done` after it.

Comment: Thanks guys. So how I do I end the 'do' loop with done?

Comment: After `esac` add `done` on the next line

Comment: Consider using `shellcheck` on your scripts. Also, I find [this reference](https://devhints.io/bash) handy.

Answer (score 0):

General example:

```
sudodus@bionic64 ~ $ select i in whoami "echo 'Hello World'" break;do $i;done
1) whoami
2) echo 'Hello World'
3) break
#? 1
sudodus
#? 2
'Hello World'
#? 3
sudodus@bionic64 ~ $
```

Example matching your question:

It is enough with a 'oneliner'.

```
$ select i in Blue Yellow Red Quit;do if [ "$i" == "Quit" ];then break;else echo "Your favorite color is $i";fi;done
1) Blue
2) Yellow
3) Red
4) Quit
#? 1
Your favorite color is Blue
#? 2
Your favorite color is Yellow
#? 3
Your favorite color is Red
#? 4
$ select i in Blue Yellow Red Quit;do if [ "$i" == "Quit" ];then break;else echo "Your favorite color is $i";fi;done
1) Blue
2) Yellow
3) Red
4) Quit
#? 4
$
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script should be :

```
do
   case $menu in
       1) echo "----------------------------"
          echo "Your favorite color is Blue!"
          echo "----------------------------"
          ;;
       2) echo "----------------------------"
          echo "Your favorite color is Yellow!"
          echo "----------------------------"
          ;;
       3) echo "----------------------------"
          echo "Your favorite color is Red!"
          echo "----------------------------"
          ;;
       4) echo "----------------------------"
          echo "Thank you!"
          echo "----------------------------"
          exit
          ;;           
       *) echo -e "Error: please try again (select 1......4)!"
   esac
done
```